# Why is my AJax code for bringing information from an API not working?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-web-api

this is my first post here, i hope i don't break any rules. If i do, please call my fails out so i can learn for the next time.

So i wrote a code that should bring information from an API to be rendered on my html page as text. The AJAX code is not working, and i don't know why, nothing shows up on the console, and i am getting only this warning from chrome:

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is
>   deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's
>   experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Here is my AJAX code: Am i doing anything wrong?

```
$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: "xxxxxxxxxx",
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  username: "xxxxxxx",
  password: "xxxxxxxxxx",
  data: '{ "id" }',
  success: function (){
    alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Warning is coming because the ajax async flag is false. That means it's a synchronous call to DB. Can you check response tab in network of chrome ?

Comment: Try to add the "error" callback function, like: ,
  `error: function(){
    alert('error!');
  }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the async to True and the warning doesn't show up anymore, but my sucess function still doesn't work which means the api isn't loaded. Note that when i use the same code for another API that is not protected with a password and a username, the code works perfectly, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I added the error function, what next?

Answer (score 0):

Observe the below code snippet it should help you out, and i advice to stick with the

```
$.ajax({...})
//Code to run if the request succeeds (is done);
//The response is passed to the function
.done(callback(json))
//Code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
//status codes are passed to the function
.fail(callback(xhr, status, errorThrown))
//Code to run regardless of success or failure;
.always(callback(xhr, status))
```

method as explained 
from jquery doc on [ajax](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btn").click(function(event) {
    var content = $("#content");
    var url = $("#url").val();



    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      data:{id:3},//observe this line, send object instead
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false
    })
    .done(function(data){
      alert('Thanks for your comment!');
      content.text(JSON.stringify(data));//convert object to string
    })
    .fail()
    .always();

  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p>
  Enter the url to fetch on the div using jquery ajax method
  <input id="url" class="" placeholder="Enter url" value="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" />
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Fetch</button>
</p>

<br>

<div id="content" class="container well">
  content is going to show here
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer. The code works with a normal API, but an API that needs aurthorization, it doesn't work. How do i fix it?

Comment: is it a token based auth or which type of auth method

Comment: Well i am not totally sure, but when i post the url in the browser, i come to a login page (username and password) and i have to put the username and password to be redirected to the API

Comment: if you can help out with the sample api to test it out, am not quite getting your point. What you are trying to say is that when you try to access an api you are redirected to enter username and password and then if successful then to the api you initially requested for right?

Comment: Yes that's right, here is the API if you could please try to open the url and see what you get: https://nfcgl.etterlid.org/api/handins/3

Comment: oh i see, coming checking it out

Comment: no test username and password, i can't signup, but you can still mark the answer as true since it atleast gives the done response.

You need to login then check if there is an api key you are to send along with your request before accessing the api, because you can't simulate login on the html page like that